# scipy.optimize() Value Error:Shape mismatch for sum

Tags: python, optimization, numpy, scipy

Hi I am new to scipy and numpy,

I am trying to use solve a QP problem for a class assignment

```
minimize x^t * H * x  + f^t * x 
where x > 0
```

Where H is a 2 X 2 block matrix with each element being a k X k dimensional matrix and 
x and f being 2 X 1 vectors with each element being a k dimension vector.

```
np.shape(H) = (2, 2, k, k)
np.shape(x) = (2, k)
```

I am getting a shape mismatch error even though the function I think is correct

Here's my implementation :

```
def func(x):    #This function runs perfectly ,returns a value 

    return 0.5 * np.tensordot(x, np.tensordot(H, x, axes=([1,3],[0,1]))) + np.tensordot(x,f)

x_init = np.ones((2, k))

bnds = (0, None)

theta = opt.minimize(func , x_init, bounds = bnds)
# I get an error here. 
# ValueError: shape-mismatch for sum
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `x_init` is being flattened by `opt.minimize`. You can workaround this by reshaping `x` inside the function:

```
def func(x):
    x = x.reshape(2, -1)
    return 0.5 * np.tensordot(x, np.tensordot(H, x, axes=([1,3],[0,1]))) + np.tensordot(x,f)
```

The result is captured by `theta` and the optimized `x` from the attribute `theta.x`, which you will see is also flattened, needing the same reshape.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Maybe I'll be better of reducing the dimensions of my matrix and vectors in the first place.